# How Can A Symfony2 Application Use The MySQL Memory Storage Engine?

Tags: mysql, symfony

MySQL offers a range of [storage engines](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/memory-storage-engine.html) and of these is the [memory storage engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/memory-storage-engine.html) that is an in-memory option.

How can I configure a Symfony2 application to tell it to tell PDO to tell MySQL to use the memory storage engine?

I'd like to do so in two cases. Firstly, I'd like to do this for the test environment such that tearing down and rebuilding the database before each unit test is a faster operation. Secondly, I'd like to apply this to a Symfony2 application where the data is relatively transient and as such it doesn't matter if all data is lost when power is lost.

Given the following example application configuration (app/config/parameters.yml), what changes would I need to make for the memory storage engine to be used?

```
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
    database_host: localhost
    database_port: null
    database_name: example
    database_user: user
    database_password: password
```

Comment: You should be able to `ALTER TABLE` after the fact to change the `ENGINE` setting, right?

Answer (score 2):

You can actually specify the engine type per table with something like:

```
@Table(name="table_name",options={"engine"="memory"})
```

That would work fine for your transient production tables.

To get something that is environment dependent (i.e. test only) would take a bit more work.  You could probably do it by modifying the metadata on the fly.  Couple of threads on doing that.

Sadly, there is no global mysql engine attribute for symfony.  At least as far as I can tell.

Comment: This might help for "on the fly" modifications: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#load-classmetadata-event